# How do I know whether my diet is good or whether it's total crap?

Tags: weight-loss, diet, muscle-gain, food

I'm trying to gain muscle and become fit without getting too pumped up. I've made this diet and my question is, how do I check if my diet is any good?

[image: diet]

**edit 1**: My warm meal isn't included but that will be mostly veggies and a small portion of red meat or chicken.

Comment: 1.6k kcal - how big are you? That's about how much a woman in her 50ies that tries to lose weight with a very moderate workout program should consume. The average male trying to build muscle should perhaps eat twice as much. It's ok if you happen to be a small person, but such information is crucial. First find out if you're eating enough, then if you are eating the right food. I don't know what you mean with warm meal, but you better include that

Comment: @Raditz_35 Thanks for your comment. According to almost all daily calorie needs calculators that i've asked, I would need around 2350 calories per day to maintain my weight. So I'm aiming to eat around 1900-2000 to lose 5-10 kg at first. And then to eat more to gain muscles. And by 'fit and not too pumped up", i mean a body like that of the user MJB: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/users/20039/mjb

which is to be seen better at his Insta:
https://www.instagram.com/mjb.insta/

Comment: Any by a warm mean i mean a meal that is typically considerd the mean meal of the day.

Comment: 2.4k kcal sounds reasonable for the average male if you don't work out. If you do work out, well, you could easily need 400 kcal or more extra. Btw, you stating that you want to lose weight is crucial information, please include it. Stating that your primary goal is gaining muscle is misleading if not wrong in that case because it implies that you want to be at a surplus.  Btw, as long as your plan is incomplete, it is useless. One can give you general advice, but not point out specific issues. If you want the general route, perhaps delete your plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you check if your diet is good, is by checking that it contains all the micronutrients you need. You need to make sure you get all your vitamins, minerals, etc.

Secondly, the way you check if it's the right diet for you is by determining if you are accomplishing your goals. Your diet should fit your goals, and if it's not helping you get there, then the diet needs to be adjusted.

Generally, the diet should provide the nutrition needed to make sure you are not chronically tired, to make sure you recover from any exercise. Since you're ostensibly looking to gain some weight (in terms of muscle), you need a bit of a caloric surplus.

These are the main factors you need to consider when making a diet. If you follow this, you can't go far wrong, and the longer you stick to this diet, and make small adjustments to it, the more you will learn about what YOUR body in particular needs. Since diet is not a one-size-fits-all thing, you will inevitably have to experiment to find out what you need, since no one can tell you outright what the perfect diet for you is.